# Calling Standard Library Functions

Tags: swift, swift3

I can't believe I don't know the answer to this (nor can easily find it online) but...

I'm working with a class that has two functions (`min()` and `max()`) that I can't alter.  Within that class, I want to use the Standard Library Function `min<T>(T, T)` (to find the minimum of two values).  Calling `min(x, y)` doesn't work.  I naïvely assumed that I would merely prefix it as `Math.min(x, y)` but that doesn't work either.

What is the correct prefix or work-around for this?

Comment: You were close: `Swift.min`

Comment: Ach!  Well done Martin, I should have thought of that one.  (Incidentally, do you ever sleep or are you really a group of people?)